# Colormap three colors

Tags: matlab, colorbar, contourf

I have a netcdf file with positive and negative currents (upwelling and downwelling respectively). I want to create a contourf where downwelling is green, upwelling is red and 0 is black. So far this is my code including some code from the Mathworks website https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81352-colormap-with-both-positive-and-negative-values :

```
%open netcdf file
ncdisp('20110810_061103.nc');
ncdisp('grid.nc');

latu=ncread('grid.nc','latitude_u');
lonu=ncread('grid.nc','longitude_u');
latv=ncread('grid.nc','latitude_v');
lonv=ncread('grid.nc','longitude_v');
u = ncread('20110810_061103.nc','vel_u'); %x axes velocity of water
v  = ncread('20110810_061103.nc','vel_v');%y axes
w  = ncread('20110810_061103.nc','w');%z axes 

Minu=min(min(min(u)))
Minv=min(min(min(v)))
Minw=min(min(min(w)))

Maxu=max(max(max(u)))
Maxv=max(max(max(v)))
Maxw=max(max(max(w)))

figure

contourf(lonu(1:681,1:711),latu(1:681,1:711),w(1:681,1:711,20))
%code I copied from mathworks    
greenColorMap = [zeros(1, 132), linspace(0, 1, 124)];
redColorMap = [linspace(1, 0, 124), zeros(1, 132)];
colorMap = [redColorMap; greenColorMap; zeros(1, 256)]';

% Apply the colormap.
colormap(colorMap);
colorbar
```

[image]

As you can see, the black is not at 0. How do I make sure that black is zero, downwelling (-) is red and upwelling(+) is green? I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I checked question [MATLAB: generating a colormap given three colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279298/matlab-generating-a-colormap-given-three-colors) but I don't understand how you set the colors and it creates something similar to the above picture. The following has nothing to do with my question although it has the same title [Matplotlib: Custom colormap with three colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952963/matplotlib-custom-colormap-with-three-colors) . 
Thank you in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with the colormap being wrong, but with the way the data values are mapped to the colormap. This is achieved by changing the `CLim` property of the underlying `axes` object with something symmetric with respect to zero, e.g.
`set(gca,'CLim',[-1e-2 1e-2])`

This can also be changed interactively through the UI: *Edit* -> *Colormap...* in the figure menu. Then edit color data min/max.